# How to get the user role in azure active directory ? asp.net core 5.0 blazor

Tags: azure-active-directory, blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-5.0

I would like to get the user role after login. I'm getting user information but role is null. please see my code below:

Initialize `services.AddHttpContextAccessor();` in ConfigureServices method in startup.cs

```
 [Inject] public IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor { get; set; }
 public string GetCurrentUser()
        {
            var roles = HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role).Select(c => c.Value).ToList(); // Please see the below image 
            return HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;   // getting login user, no issue here          
        }
```

user has assign 3 roles but here not getting any roles. How can get roles ? Thanks

[image]

Appsettings.json file configuration.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem getting ClaimsPrincipal was empty, so I found a solution it is about 2FA, when you enable 2FA and on next login if you checked remember this browser for 2fa and you remove 2fa from your account, it signs-out in some pages and losing Claims.
Try to clear cookies.
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/5817#issuecomment-491818987